# how can i configur AD Hoc distribution for a iphone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how can i create AD Hoc distribution for my iphone product.

Answer (score 2):

When you are logged into the "iPhone Developer Program Portal", download and read the "Program Portal User Guide" which is on the right. Following that guide solves a lot of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure you read and follow [Craig Hockenberry's instructions](http://furbo.org/2008/08/06/beta-testing-on-iphone-20/) to the letter.  They will save you a lot of time.

Comment: That's a little dated at this point, the program portal actually has pretty good instructions now (even covering the get-task-allow thing)

Answer (score 0):

Go into www.developer.apple.com > Login > iOS dev centre > Provisioning portal

In Provision > Distribution generate a new profile using "ad hoc" distribution

Download the provisioning profile. Add it to iTunes using drag and drop or File > Add to Library

In Xcode create a new archive by right click on the project > Edit scheme > Archive > Ok

In the Xcode > Window > Organizer select the archive and click share

To use iTunes to sync the app select iOS App Store Package (.ipa)

Find the generated file in Finder and add to iTunes

Attach the device to iTunes and perform a sync to add the application

See:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeArchive.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010402-CH6

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a lengthy tutorial on this with screen shots here:
http://www.cannonballbounce.com/content/iphone-wireless-ad-hoc-app-distribution